# display a particular number from dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way in dropdownlist to show the desired number on pageload?

eg. 
I have a dropdownlist control

I am using a for loop to populate it

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

Now this displays 1 on page load ... but I want to display 7..
How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that it is the default selected value, you would just need to set a default selected value in the page load, after the list has been populated. Make sure only to do this when it is not a postback or you will overwrite any user selections.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    { 
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "7"
    }
}
```

Comment: just perfect..
and thanks for the postback info....
it helped me in figuring out many things...

Answer (score 2):

Would set it inside your for loop. Would also store the default somewhere outside the code (db, config) so if it changes you don't have to redeploy.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
     for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) 
     { 
        var newItem = new ListItem(i.ToString());
        newItem.Selected = (i == 7);
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(newItem); 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After your `for` loop

```
DropDownList1.Items.FindByText("7").Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem.aspx) or [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.selectedindex.aspx) property.